# Images not showing in GridView even though asset specified in pubspec.yaml Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I am developing a menu kiosk app right now, and I have some problems loading the images on my app, I made sure to specify each image in my pubspec.yaml but the images still does not show. The error i'm getting is this: 
`════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
Unable to load asset: assets/images/sideDesserts/Dippers with Choco Dip.png
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════`

Here is what my pubspec.yaml contains

```
# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/sideNav/
    #pizza assets
    - assets/images/pizza/Hawaiian Overload.png
    - assets/images/pizza/Bacon Overload.png
    - assets/images/pizza/All In Overload.png
    - assets/images/pizza/All Beef Overload.png
    - assets/images/pizza/hamandCheese.png
    - assets/images/pizza/Peperroni Classic.png
    - assets/images/pizza/veggies_cheesedouble.png
    - assets/images/pizza/Ham Pineapple Classic.png
    - assets/images/pizza/Cheese Classic.png
    #barkada assets
    - assets/images/barkada/Barkada Bundle A.png
    - assets/images/barkada/Barkada Bundle B.png
    - assets/images/barkada/Barkada Bundle C.png

    #chicken assets        
    - assets/images/chicken/1pc Chicken with Rice.png
    - assets/images/chicken/2pc Chicken Meal with Rice.png
    - assets/images/chicken/Chicken Waves.png
    #combo assets
    - assets/images/combo/Carbonara Chicken Combo.png
    - assets/images/combo/Creamy Bacon Carbonara Value Meal.png
    - assets/images/combo/Lasagna Chicken Combo.png
    - assets/images/combo/Lasagna Supreme Value Meal.png
    - assets/images/combo/Meaty Spaghetti Chicken Combo.png
    - assets/images/combo/Meaty Spaghetti Value Meal.png
    - assets/images/combo/Pizza Value Meal A.png
    - assets/images/combo/Pizza Value Meal B.png
    - assets/images/combo/Pizza Value Meal C.png
    - assets/images/combo/Pizza Loaded Combo D.png
    - assets/images/combo/Pizza Loaded Combo E.png
    #drink assets
    - assets/images/drinks/Choco Slush.png
    - assets/images/drinks/coke pitcher.png    
    - assets/images/drinks/Coke Zero.png
    - assets/images/drinks/Coke.png    
    - assets/images/drinks/Coke Glass.png
    - assets/images/drinks/Ice Tea.png
    - assets/images/drinks/Nestea Glass.png
    - assets/images/drinks/Nestea Pitcher.png    
    - assets/images/drinks/PJ Pitcher.png
    - assets/images/drinks/Pj.png
    - assets/images/drinks/Sprite.png    
    #pasta assets
    - assets/images/pasta/Lasagna Supreme Ala Carte.png
    - assets/images/pasta/Meaty Spaghetti Ala Carte.png
    - assets/images/pasta/Creamy Bacon Carbonara Ala Carte.png
    - assets/images/pasta/Lasagna Supreme Large Pan.png
    - assets/images/pasta/Meaty Spaghetti Large Pan.png
    - assets/images/pasta/Creamy Bacon Carbonara Pan.png
    - assets/images/pasta/Lasagna Supreme Pan.png
    - assets/images/pasta/Meaty Spaghetti Regular Pan.png
    - assets/images/pasta/Creamy Bacon Carbonara Regular Pan.png

    #sides Desserts assets
    - assets/images/sideDesserts/Regular Potato Waves.png
    - assets/images/sideDesserts/Cheesy Bread Sticks with Dip.png
    - assets/images/sideDesserts/Dippers with Choco Dip.png
    - assets/images/sideDesserts/Large Potato Waves.png
    - assets/images/sideDesserts/Plain Rice.png                   

    #logos
    - assets/images/Logos/box Logo.png
    - assets/images/Logos/long logo.png
```

I also created custom static List models for the different menu types, an example is this:

```
class BarkadaData {
  String name;
  String imagePath;
  double price;

  BarkadaData({this.imagePath, this.name, this.price});

  static List<BarkadaData> barkadaList = [
    BarkadaData(
        name: 'Barkada Bundle A (for 3)',
        price: 469.00,
        imagePath: 'assets/images/barkada/Barkada Bundle A.png'),
    BarkadaData(
        name: 'Barkada Bundle B (for 4)',
        price: 569.00,
        imagePath: 'assets/images/barkada/Barkada Bundle B.png'),
    BarkadaData(
        name: 'Barkada Bundle C (for 6)',
        price: 969.00,
        imagePath: 'assets/images/barkada/Barkada Bundle C.png'),
  ];
}
```

Lastly, i'm displaying it using a GridView.builder my widget tree looks like this:

```
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .75,
                        child: GridView.builder(
                          itemCount: barkadaList.length,
                          gridDelegate:
                              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  crossAxisCount: 3),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                print(barkadaList[index].name);
                              },
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                          .22,
                                      child: Image(
                                        image: AssetImage(
                                            barkadaList[index].imagePath),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '${barkadaList[index].name}',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                          fontSize: 18),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      )
```

[image]

As you can see, the gridview.builder works because the names are displaying, only images are not. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your image. Your image name has space. In android image not load with space name. so Refactor your image name **Dippers with Choco Dip** to **Dippers_with_Choco_Dip**

Comment: Thank you so much! Is the convention same for iOS? Does assets wont load if it has whitespaces?

Comment: IOS can support image names with "_". So for both OS support use name with "_". N.B: IOS also supports image name with special character but android not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, fix your pubspec.yaml like this.

from

```
- assets/images/barkada/Barkada Bundle A.png
```

to

```
- 'assets/images/barkada/Barkada Bundle A.png'
```